# How to write Integration Test with the usage of Bearer Token in Spring Boot (throw An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, junit, bearer-token

I have a problem to write Integration Test in my Spring Boot example.
In my UserController class, every methods are defined with @PreAuthorize with roles.

Here is my code snippets shown below

Here is the AbstractRestControllerTest  shown below

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public abstract class AbstractRestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

}
```

Here is the Controller in my Spring Boot Project

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    private final UserToUserResponseMapper userToUserResponseMapper = UserToUserResponseMapper.initialize();
    private final UserToUsersResponseMapper userToUsersResponseMapper = UserToUsersResponseMapper.initialize();

    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')")
    public Response<Void> saveUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserSaveRequest saveRequest) {
        userService.saveUser(saveRequest);
        return Response.SUCCESS;
    }
```

Here is my IntegrationTest Class shown below

```
class UserControllerTest extends AbstractRestControllerTest {

     @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    private static final String BASE_PATH = "/api/v1/user";

    @Test
    void saveUserRequestWithAdminRole_ReturnSuccess() throws Exception {
        // Given
        UserSaveRequest mockUserSaveRequest = new UserSaveRequestBuilder()
                .withFirstName("First Name")
                .build();
        Token mockToken = TokenBuilder.VALID_FOR_ADMIN;
        Response<Void> mockResponse = ResponseBuilder.SUCCESS;

        // When
        Mockito.doNothing().when(userService).saveUser(mockUserSaveRequest);

        // Then
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post(BASE_PATH, mockToken.getAccessToken(), mockUserSaveRequest))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.time").isNotEmpty())              .andExpect(jsonPath("$.httpStatus").value(mockResponse.getHttpStatus().getReasonPhrase()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.isSuccess").value(mockResponse.getIsSuccess()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.response").doesNotExist());

        Mockito.verify(userService, Mockito.times(1)).saveUser(Mockito.any());

    }
}
```

Here is the TokenBuilder class shown below

```
public class TokenBuilder {

    public static final Token VALID_FOR_ADMIN = Token.builder()
            .accessToken("ACCESS_TOKEN")
            .accessTokenExpiresAt(LONG_VALUE)
            .refreshToken("REFRESH_TOKEN")
            .build();

    public static final Token VALID_FOR_USER = Token.builder()
            .accessToken("ACCESS_TOKEN")
            .accessTokenExpiresAt(LONG_VALUE)
            .refreshToken("REFRESH_TOKEN")
            .build();

}
```

Here is the MockMvcRequestBuilders class shown below

```
@Slf4j
@UtilityClass
public class MockMvcRequestBuilders {

public MockHttpServletRequestBuilder post(String endpoint, String token, Object requestBody) {
        return MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(endpoint)
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token)
                .content(GSON.toJson(requestBody))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      }
}
```

I got this issue shown below when I run saveUserRequestWithAdminRole_ReturnSuccess

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

How can I fix the test method in IntegrationTest of Controller?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have this or not in your code, it could be that you have it but not copied it here.

In the code you need to catch the request that contains the bearer token and translate that into a Sping Authentication object. This is done in a special flter that will run prior to the standard auth filkters. Its sole job is to setup the authentication. We use three components to do this:

- A filter to intercept the HTTP request, This is a component class that extends the OncePerSession class. You override the  method "doFilterInternal" to find the token.
- A utility that decodes the token and ensures it is valid. We have a component called JWTUtilities to do this. We alsoi use this to generate tokens, rather than construct them manually as you do. So Our first call is to get the token, then we use that to test the endpoints.
- We use our standard Session UserDetails class to cross reference a token user to a database user. We supply our users with an APIKEY and APISECRET.  The key translates to a user in the database, and by looking up the user we get a list or roles they are suppose to have. This code is largely shared with the end user login that we get from ThymeLeaf and our web pages login.

As an example, here is what we use for the JWT Token Filter.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    @NonNull private JwtUtils jwtUtil;
    @NonNull private SessionUserDetails sessionUserDetails; 
    
    /**
     * Do filter internal.
     *
     * @param request     the http request
     * @param response    the http response
     * @param filterChain the filter chain 
     * @throws ServletException the servlet exception
     * @throws IOException      Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(header) && header.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            String token = header.split(" ")[1].trim();
            if (jwtUtil.validateJwtToken(token)) {
                // We have a bearer token and it is valid. 
                // Decode the token to get the username and then construct 
                // an authentication token. 
                
                Claims claims = jwtUtil.parseClaims(token);
                String userName = (String) claims.get(Claims.SUBJECT);
                log.debug("Username subject {} " , userName);

                UserDetails userDetails = sessionUserDetails.loadUserByUsername(userName);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken 
                    authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                authentication.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue is related with Integration Test Part. Not Filter part. Can you revise your answer?

Comment: Not really. The error you are getting states quite clearly that Spring Boot is missing an Authentication object . That filter is what creates this object. Do you have such a filter?

Comment: I already had a filter.

Comment: Then the only thing I an suggest is that you have a malformed JWT. I would but a debug breakpoint in the OncePerRequestFilter and see what it is doing. This filter does not seem to be passing back a SecurityContext. With out this Security Context yo are not going to get the authentication of your jwt.